# How do I list my gists?

Tags: github, gist

Can I get a listing of my gists?

Such a listing would list all gists, not only four and not show the contents of a gist until I click it.

Comment: You can try [gifc](https://github.com/armsp/gifc) too if you are okay with using a cli tool written in Python.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a simple way:
https://gist.github.com/anders

just put user name in the end of the url: gist.github.com/[user name]

Comment: That menu does not take me to that page.

Comment: @AndersLindén you're right. I will edit the answer but the link I provided works for you, right?

Answer (score 6):

Use GitHub Gist API: https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#list-a-users-gists

For example, list all public Gist of user `anders`: https://api.github.com/users/anders/gists

a part of return result:

```
"html_url": "https://gist.github.com/5b2bd534992dafe3f05202d43d8e48a2",
```

Then access: https://gist.github.com/5b2bd534992dafe3f05202d43d8e48a2 you will see detail content of this specific gist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What I seek is a way to have the github page presenting my gists in a list fashion.

Comment: You write a small program for parsing JSON, and display only your Gist's URL HTML links.

Comment: So the answer is that the github webpage in itself does not provide any way of listing gists as a list?

Comment: GitHub hasn't a built-in feature what display all gist as a list.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40723928/6243352) correctly suggests retrieving public gist information with the free, unauthenticated, cors-enabled API: `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/gists`.

However, the answer doesn't mention that the initial request only returns the first page. To get all public gists for a user, iterate the pages until you see an empty array response (I guess you could save a request if any returns less than the maximum page size, which appears to be 30). Here's an example in JS for convenience:

```js
const fetchJson = (...args) =>
  fetch(...args).then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.status);
    }

    return response.json();
  });

const fetchGists = async (username, maxPages=10) => {
  const gists = [];

  for (let page = 1; page <= maxPages; page++) {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/gists?page=${page}`;
    const chunk = await fetchJson(url);

    if (chunk.length === 0) {
      break;
    }
 
    gists.push(...chunk);
  }

  return gists;
};

fetchGists("gaearon").then(gists => {
  // for all fields:
  //document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(gists, null, 2);

  // ...or select interesting fields:
  gists = gists.map(({
    description, files, html_url, created_at, updated_at
  }) => ({
    description, files, html_url, created_at, updated_at
  })).sort((a, b) => b.updated_at.localeCompare(a.updated_at));
  document.body.textContent =
    `total number of public gists: ${gists.length}
${JSON.stringify(gists, null, 2)}`;
});
```

```css
body {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

Caution: the rate limit at the time of writing is 60 requests per hour, which is easy to exceed. You can monitor your current rate limits in the response headers:

```
x-ratelimit-limit: 60
x-ratelimit-remaining: 0
x-ratelimit-reset: 1664391218
x-ratelimit-resource: core
x-ratelimit-used: 60
```

Here's a more comprehensive example which shows the rate limits and gists and a prettier interface. I [host a version on GitHub pages](https://ggorlen.github.io/gist-list) so I can easily find my gists (the built-in GitHub website gist page is awkward to click through 10 items at a time and has poor search functionality):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Gist List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/github-markdown-css/5.1.0/github-markdown-dark.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2.5em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .markdown-body {
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .github-limits {
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
  }

  .gists ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
  }

  .gists th {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
  }

  .gists .sorted-desc:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.5em;
    content: "\25BC";
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }

  .gists .sorted-asc:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.5em;
    content: "\25B2";
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }

  .github-logo {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1.5em;
    top: 1.5em;
  }

  td, th {
    min-width: 75px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }

  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .markdown-body {
      padding: 15px;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 467px) {
    .markdown-body {
      padding: 10px;
    }

    td, th {
      min-width: 70px;
      font-size: 0.8em;
    }
  }
</style>
</head>
<body class="markdown-body">
  <div class="github-logo">
    <a href="https://github.com/ggorlen/gist-list">
      <img src="https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/site/icons/footer/github-mark.svg" alt="GitHub mark" width="20" height="20">
    </a>
  </div>
  <h1>Gist List</h1>
  <div>
    <form class="gist-search">
      <input
        class="github-username"
        placeholder="Enter a GitHub username"
        autofocus
      >
      <input type="submit" value="search">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="github-limits"></div>
  <div class="gists"></div>
<script>

"use strict";

class GHRequestError extends Error {
  constructor(limits = {}, ...params) {
    super(...params);

    if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, GHRequestError);
    }

    this.name = "GHRequestError";
    this.limits = limits;
  }
}

const fetchJson = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(async response => {
  const {headers} = response;
  const limits = {
    remaining: headers.get("x-ratelimit-remaining"),
    limit: headers.get("x-ratelimit-limit"),
    reset: new Date(headers.get("x-ratelimit-reset") * 1000),
  };

  if (!response.ok) {
    const message = response.statusText || response.status;
    throw new GHRequestError(limits, message);
  }

  return {limits, payload: await response.json()};
});

const fetchGists = async (username, maxPages=10) => {
  const gists = [];
  let limits;

  for (let page = 1; page <= maxPages; page++) {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/gists?page=${page}`;
    const {limits: lastLimits, payload: chunk} = await fetchJson(url);
    limits = lastLimits;

    if (chunk.length === 0) {
      break;
    }
 
    gists.push(...chunk);
  }

  return {limits, gists};
};

const firstFile = gist =>
  Object.keys(gist.files).length
    ? Object.values(gist.files)[0].filename : "";


const gistDescription = gist => `
  <a href="${gist.html_url}">
    ${gist.description || (
      Object.keys(gist.files).length
        ? firstFile(gist)
        : "<em>no description</em>"
      )
    }
  </a>
`;

const gistFiles = gist => `
  <ul>
  ${Object.values(gist.files)
    .map(e => `
      <li><a href="${e.raw_url}">${e.filename}</a></li>
    `)
    .join("")}
  </ul>
`;

const gistTableRow = gist => `
  <tr>
    <td>
      ${gistDescription(gist)}
    </td>
    <td>
      ${gistFiles(gist)}
    </td>
    <td>
      ${gist.created_at.slice(0, 10)}
    </td>
    <td>
      ${gist.updated_at.slice(0, 10)}
    </td>
  </tr>
`;

const gistsTable = gists => 
  gists.length === 0 ? "<div>No gists found</div>" : `
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        ${headers.map(({name}) => `<th>${name}</th>`).join("")}
      </tr>
      ${gists.map(gistTableRow).join("")}
    </tbody>
  </table>
`;

const listenToHeaderClick = header => {
  header.addEventListener("click", ({target: {textContent}}) => {
    let {key, ascending} = headers.find(e => e.name === textContent);

    if (sortedBy === textContent) {
      gists.reverse();
      ascending = header.classList.contains("sorted-desc");
    }
    else {
      sortedBy = textContent;
      gists.sort((a, b) => key(a).localeCompare(key(b)));

      if (!ascending) {
        gists.reverse();
      }
    }

    gistsToDOM(gists);
    showSortedIcon(ascending);
  });
};

const gistsToDOM = gists => {
  document.querySelector(".gists").innerHTML = gistsTable(gists);
  document.querySelectorAll(".gists th").forEach(listenToHeaderClick);
};

const limitsToDOM = limits => {
  document.querySelector(".github-limits").innerHTML = `
    <small>
      <em>
        ${limits.remaining}/${limits.limit} API requests remaining.
        Usage resets at ${limits.reset}.
      </em>
    </small>
  `;
};

const showSortedIcon = ascending => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".gists th").forEach(e => {
    if (e.textContent === sortedBy) {
      e.classList.add(ascending ? "sorted-asc" : "sorted-desc");
    }
  });
};

const handleGistsResponse = response => {
  ({limits, gists} = response);
  limitsToDOM(limits);
  gistsToDOM(gists);
  showSortedIcon(headers.find(e => e.name === sortedBy).ascending);
};

const handleError = err => {
  const gistsEl = document.querySelector(".gists");
  gistsEl.innerHTML = err.message;
  limitsToDOM(err.limits);
};

const searchGists = username => {
  const submit = document.querySelector(".gist-search [type='submit']");
  submit.disabled = true;
  fetchGists(username)
    .then(handleGistsResponse)
    .catch(handleError)
    .finally(() => submit.disabled = false);
};

const trySearchFromURLParam = () => {
  const username = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("username");
  
  if (username) {
    const unEl = document.querySelector(".github-username");
    unEl.value = username;
    searchGists(username);
  }
};

const listenForSubmit = () => {
  document.querySelector(".gist-search")
    .addEventListener("submit", event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const {value} = event.target.querySelector(".github-username");
      searchGists(value);
    });
};

let limits;
let gists;
let sortedBy = "Updated";

const headers = Object.freeze([
  {
    name: "Description",
    key: e => e.description || firstFile(e),
    ascending: true,
  },
  {
    name: "Files",
    key: firstFile,
    ascending: true,
  },
  {
    name: "Created",
    key: e => e.created_at,
    ascending: false,
  },
  {
    name: "Updated",
    key: e => e.updated_at,
    ascending: false,
  },
]);

trySearchFromURLParam();
listenForSubmit();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your "hosted on GitHub pages" version is BRILLIANT. I used `inspect > head > copy element` to get the "computed" page to store as a static file. That way I don't add unnecessary load to your limits. I've wanted a simple listing of all my gists for *ages*. Thanks!

Comment: @Dɑvïd thanks, but I think the limit shown is your limit, not mine or a shared limit, so there's no need to cache unless you're planning on exceeding the limit yourself. I appreciate the thought though.

Answer (score 0):

## You can use the github API

> for example:

- [***MY Gists***](https://api.github.com/users/bgoonz/gists)

`https://api.github.com/users/{your git username}/gists`

##### produces a json file like seen below:

[image: githubjson]

Comment: Thanks but this answer is basically the same as [this one from 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40723928/6243352). I would just upvote that one instead of adding a virtually identical answer.